# I want to pass back a variable from a promt box to the date string

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass back a variable from a promt box to the date string. So if a person adds 5 days the date will bump up 5 days. I am new to javascript and this is my first test script any resources you could list in your answer I will read up on.

```
<html>

 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var currentTime = new Date();
     var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
     var day = currentTime.getDate();
     var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
     var dateString = "Today's Date " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
     function loadDate(){
       document.getElementById('dateSpan').innerHTML = dateString;
     }

   </script>

 </head>
 <body onload='loadDate()'>
   <form name=myform>
     <span id='dateSpan'></span><input type=button value="add days" onclick="var name=prompt('How many days do you want to add?','5 or 6')"/>
   </form>
 </body>
```

Comment: The format m/d/y is only used by a very small proportion of the world's population, you should use an unambiguous format (e.g. 2 March 2012)or an ISO8601 standard format (e.g. 2012-03-02).

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should help. Note that it doesn't do any validation or checking (is the date string correct in the element? did the user enter a number?) so you'll need to add all that and deal with errors.

```
function updateDate(el) {
  // get the text of the element
  var text = el.innerHTML;

  // Convert to a date object
  var b = text.split('-');
  var date = new Date(b[0], b[1] - 1, b[2]);

  // Ask for days to add
  var toAdd = prompt('How many days to add?');

  // Adjust date
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + Number(toAdd));

  // Write date to page
  el.innerHTML = date.getFullYear() + '-' + 
                 addZ(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
                 addZ(date.getDate());

  // Helper just for this function
  function addZ(n) {
    return (n < 10? '0' : '') + n;
  }
}
```

And some related HTML:

```
<span id="dateSpan" onclick="updateDate(this)">2012-05-22</span>
```

Note also that innerHTML gets all the HTML content too, but for something like this it shoudl be fine. If you need just the text, then use either [textContent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent) or [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) based on a feature test for which is supported.

#### Edit

Added a snipped of HTML to make it work. Note that the date is an ISO8601 short form: year-month-day.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with using the date.js lib.

This makes dates a lot easier to work with and it's well documented too.

http://www.datejs.com/

Then once you have the number of days to add you can easily bump the date up.

```
//Assuming Xdays is a var with your number of days.
var today = Date.today();
var past = Date.today().add(-Xdays).days();
var future = Date.today().add(Xdays).days();

//format to a string
Date.today().toString("d-MMM-yyyy"); // 19-Nov-2007
```